# XML Return parent node when searching children

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```
<Log>
<Log>
    <Log>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <Guid>16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00085</Guid>
    </Log>
</Log>
<Log>
    <Log>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <Guid>16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00086</Guid>
    </Log>
</Log>
<Log>
    <Log>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <Guid>16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00087</Guid>
    </Log>
</Log>
</Log>
```

I would like to return the 2nd element Log and below when searching for Guid, eg

```
<Log>
    <Log>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <Guid>16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00085</Guid>
    </Log>
</Log>
```

I've tried all sorts using linq to xml but can't seem to get it right, can anyone help?

```
    XElement Log = XElement.Parse(responseXml)
    .Elements("Log")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Guid").Value == "16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00085")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Is it correct for all the GUIDs to be the same?

Comment: no sorry, just cut n paste, i've corrected it!

Comment: You need find if Guid exists, or you need to return parent elements of Log with your Guid?

Comment: I need to return an XElement 2 levels above the Guid, shown in the 2nd code block above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Linq and XPath (add reference to `System.Xml.XPath` namespace):

```
var guid = "16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00086";
var log = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//Log[Log/Guid]")
              .Where(g => (string)g.XPathSelectElement("Log/Guid") == guid)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Expression `//Log[Log/Guid]` selects all `Log` elements, which have at least one `Log` child with inner `Guid` element. Code above returns:

```
<Log>
  <Log></Log>
  <Log>
    <Guid>16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00086</Guid>
  </Log>
</Log>
```

---

Or with simple Linq. You can use [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.parent.aspx) property. But in this case you need to be sure, that all `Guid` elements are nested only within at least two `Log` elements

```
var guid = "16fea409-58cc-e211-9b7f-005056b00086";
var log = xdoc.Descendants("Guid")
              .Where(g => (string) g == guid)
              .Select(g => g.Parent.Parent)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```